# Problems with django cookies

Tags: python, django, cookies, browser

How do you properly set cookies in Django?

I have tried this:

```
 re=HttpResponse('Hello world')
 re.set_cookie('key','value')
```

and also this:

```
 request.COOKIES['key']='value'
```

None of these are working and I have yet to figure out why.

**Edit 1** 
Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
 lang=UserData.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)  
 lang.pref_language=request.POST.get('lang','')  
 re=HttpResponse('Hello world') 
 re.set_cookie('dddd',request.POST.get('lang','') )
 request.COOKIES['ffff']=request.POST.get('lang','')           
 lang.save()
 return HttpResponse('Updated')
```

so language is being saved every time function runs but cookies are not working properly.

Comment: You'll need to give more details. What are you doing with that response? How are you verifying that it is "not working"?

Comment: You are returning a new `HttpResponse` object instead of the `re` object that you set a cookie on... i.e., your modifications to `re` are discarded. Also there is no point modifying `request.COOKIES`. That is a request object, not a response object.

Comment: solarissmoke  I can I modify it to make it work???

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out that the reason why cookies are not set is that I am nor returning my response object . Here is final  version

```
re=HttpResponse('/')  
re.set_cookie('language',request.POST.get('lang','') ) 
return re
```